# What does a complex integral mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-integration

I want to know what a complex integral means. I know normal integration of suppose $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ gives the area of the curve $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$.

In the same way what does an integral of a complex function, say $f(z)$ (along a path $C$) represent?

Comment: Note that, with a real integral, the direction of integration matters. $\int_a^b$ is the negative of $\int_b^a$. A similar thing happens for complex integrals.

Comment: So does the complex integral also give the area enclosed?

Comment: No. The path might have two different endpoints, so it wouldn't enclose an area. Do you know the formula? (I'm not actually sure I know a good intuition)

Comment: $$\int_cf(z)dz$$, yes i am familiar with it. Does it give the path along C? i am confused

Comment: Not that formula, I meant the [Riemann sum given over here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral) (in the section on complex line integrals).